# How can I rewrite this CSS for react native

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error when writing this CSS property for react native.

```
border-radius: 50% / 100%;
```

I try to do:

```
borderRadius: '50% / 100%'
```

I got an error that Java.lang.string cannot be cast to java.lang.double

Answer (score 1):

Split the shorthand property of [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) to avoid the use of `/`:

```
border-radius: 50% / 100%;
```

Become this:

```
border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 100%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 100%;
```

Comment: Still having that issue, I did:                                
               `borderBottomLeftRadius: '50% 100%',
                 borderBottomRightRadius: '50% 100%',
                borderTopLeftRadius: '50% 100%',
                borderTopRightRadius: '50% 100%'`

Answer (score 0):

In react-native we can't set percentage on borderRadius, you have to use numbers.

You can set a high borderRadius, then use `onLayout` to get the actual width of the view and then set the border radius. Or just set a high borderRadius.

Most preferably though, you know the dimensions, and just use that divided by 2.